# How can I decode a utf8 NSstring on iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have an NSstring that is encoded with UTF8. I want to decode it.

**I tried this but it doesn't work:**

```
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[encodedString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sending `cStringUsingEncoding:` to `encodedString` can only work if `encodedString` is an NSString object. Having an NSString object is the point you're trying to get to. Moreover, that method does not *decode* the string, it *encodes* the string using the encoding you ask for; thus, in the code you show, you ask for the (already-encoded) string to be encoded in some random encoding (the default C string encoding), then attempt to decode the result as UTF-8. That won't work.

You don't specify what type you're using for `encodedString`. Either way, you need to create the NSString object by passing `encodedString` and its encoding.

- If `encodedString` is an NSData object, use [the `initWithData:encoding:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:).
- If it's a null-terminated C string; use [the `initWithCString:encoding:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithCString:encoding:) or (only when it's UTF-8) [the `initWithUTF8String:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithUTF8String:).
- If it's just plain (unterminated) bytes, use [the `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithBytes:length:encoding:).

All of these except `initWithUTF8String:` require you to specify the encoding (`initWithUTF8String:` does by definition), and all of them except `initWithData:encoding:` come in an autoreleasing convenience version (`+stringWith…` instead of `-initWith…`).